# How to get DAY of the WEEK from the datetime format in JAVA?

Tags: java, dayofweek

I have date time information in this format:

```
String reportDate="2012-04-19 12:32:24";
```

I want to have as output day of the week (Thursday or 4 as result anyway is good).
How to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Calendar` after parsing the string:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS");
Date d = sdf.parse(reportDate);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(d);
return cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Comment: For 2012-04-19 12:32:24 it returns me 5? is it OK? does it start to count from Sunday as first?

Comment: Yes it start's with Sunday. Have a look at Calendar.THURSDAY which is 5.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse the `String` then you have a `Date` object an can get the day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

Parse your date to an actual `Date` Object and then pass it to a [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) Instance (through [setTime(Date date)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTime%28java.util.Date%29)). You can then use the [DAY_OF_WEEK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK) to get a number representing the days of the week.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("E").format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(reportDate)));
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("F").format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(reportDate)));
```